# How many contexts are too many contexts? A question about designing a Svelte library with Floating-UI

Tags: svelte, floating-ui

I am in the process of creating a Svelte library for a customized Bootstrap theme.  The idea is to only use the CSS and ditch all of the JavaScript.

I am currently in the floating parts of the library.  Things like menus and tooltips.  I started with tooltips and I am having a hard time zeroing on a design I like.

### Floating-UI Requirement

The Floating-UI library requires the html elements of the reference and the target elements to perform the calculations.  No problem with `bind:this` except for a scenario where I have dozens of components that may show a floating UI.  That would fill the parent with dozens of variables to hold the references, or an array which is not ideal in my head because it is then not easy to know which is which.

Also, I will be needing `show` boolean variables for every floating UI in the dozens as well.

So I played with the idea of slots, and I have been partly successful in creating markup like this:

```html
<Button fuiTriggerOpts={{ hideTriggers: Triggers.Focus, showTriggers: Triggers.Focus }}>
    <svelte:fragment slot="content">
        Focus me!
    </svelte:fragment>
    <Tooltip shadow={true} slot="floatUi" placement="top-start" let:reference referenceEl={reference}>
        <div class="fancy-tooltip">
            <div class="big">
                <Icon name="keyboard" />
            </div>
            <p>I only appear or disappear on <strong>keyboard focus</strong> events.</p>
        </div>
    </Tooltip>
</Button>
```

The advantages:

- I don't pollute the parent component's script tag with variables to hold references.  Instead, I get the parent reference from a slot variable and pass it to the tooltip.
- I made the button declare its own `show` variable for the purposes of handling showing and hiding the tooltip or whatever floating UI is given to it.
- It doesn't complicate things too much (ignore the fuiTrigger things you see for now).

The disadvantages:

- A maximum of one floating UI can be paired with the element (button in this case).  If I wanted a tooltip and a menu, I cannot.
- I have to repeat this type of slot construction for every component I suspect can have a floating UI associated to it.  If I'm fair about it, it could potentially be any component:  Icons, buttons, splitters, resizers, checkboxes, radios, etc.

So here comes my next idea:  What if controls published a reference to its root element as context using `setContext()`?  That would allow me to code the Tooltip and other floating UI elements with `getContext()` and then I don't have to pass references around or having them in variables.  But then it means that pretty much every control in the library would do this `setContext()` thing (see the last disadvantage).

My main question is:  Would this be abusing the context system?  Is this too many contexts?  A complex page could probably reach 100 contexts.

While that's my main question, I'll be happy to hear completely different alternatives to approach the original problem easier.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to, for example, define a `<Button>` and a `<Tooltip>` and/or `<Menu>` component, then somehow "link" those together?

Comment: Yes, something like that.  But it could be that I want to link to floating elements to one reference element.  I think the ideal scenario would be if Svelte itself could export the HTML element reference for components that need to expose it.  Of course, that is just wishful thinking, so back to reality:  I would like to have an easy way of linking 2 elements.  Today is for floating-ui; tomorrow, who knows!

Comment: Hmmm, this is a really interesting architectural challenge... My first instinct is to emulate the dynamic between `<label>`'s `for` and `<input>`'s `id`. You shouldn't use `id` in components though, they should be reusable while `id`'s must be unique. I played around with a `linkTarget` [action](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/actions), but discovered that those can only be applied to vanilla DOM elements... I'll have to think about this some more later.

Comment: The problem with context in this _context_ (ha) is that you can only set context for the current component, and only read context from the parent(s). That means you'd have to establish some form of parent-child relation (through slots) between the controls and floats for them to be able to communicate, which leads to the "controls need specific support" issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This idea sounds analogous to the dynamic between `<label>`'s `for` and `<input>`'s `id` attribute.
You can't use `id` inside a Svelte component though, because they should be reusable and `id`'s must be unique by definition.

The problem with context in this *context* (ha) is that you can only set context for the current component, and only read context set by parent(s). That means you'd have to establish some form of parent-child relation (through slots) between the controls and floats.
This complicates your markup significantly and as already you mentioned requires explicitly built-in support in the target component and gets tricky with multiple 'floats' per component.

I played around with `use:`-directives and funky higher-order-components for a bit, but in the end I realized the simplest solution is usually the best one:

```html
<script>
    let linkTargets = {};
</script>

<Button bind:this={linkTargets.focusButton}>
    Focus me!
</Button>

<Tooltip target={linkTargets.focusButton}>
    I only appear or disappear on <strong>keyboard focus</strong> events.
</Tooltip>
```

Just like an array you only need one variable to hold all the references, but by using an object you get descriptive key names, just like `for` and `id` :)

Comment: Thanks, but this cannot possibly work as floating-ui requires HTML elements.  Binding to the component is not the same as binding to the underlying HTML the component renders.  You are passing an instance of the Button component class, not a reference to the HTMLButtonElement object, which is what is required by floating-ui.

Comment: In that case `Button` will have to expose its root DOM element somehow,  for example by defining a `bind:dom`. All possible solutions would need something like this, I'm guessing your slot-based variant does it with a `bind:this` inside the `Button` component. It's annoying, but requires less drastic changes compared to the slots-based approach and it supports multiple floats per target :)

Comment: I understand, hence my question and dilemma.  At this point you have arrived to the same conclusions I did.  If this is the only solution, then I think that publishing the element reference as context would be the best option, as floating UI components can just pick up their reference element from context, which brings me to the original question.

Comment: @JoséRamírez I don't see how this would be better. Using context instead of a simple `bind:this` here creates a _lot_ of extra complexity for little to no gain. You can't publish the target without establishing a child-parent relationship. This requires drastic changes to _every_ component that could be a floater-target (code duplication), it would be impossible to support any vanilla DOM element or components outside of your control, massively complicates your markup, which gets even more tricky when you need multiple floaters per target and near impossible when you need multiple targets per

Comment: Context establishes an implicit coupling that makes it harder to reason about your application's data flow. It definitely has its place when this coupling is unavoidable/expected and there already is a parent-child relationship (like `<table>`/`<tr>` and `<select>`/`<option>`) but as far as I can tell this is not one of those cases.